# Видеокарта хорошо греется даже если программно отключена

Tags: linux, debian, железо, видеокарта

Есть старый компьютер. Долго валялся без дела, захотелось использовать в качестве сервера, 5 гигабайт RAM как ни как, так вот. Была проблема, что он не запускался без видеокарты, биос не позволял, а интегрированной нет. Была куплена дешёвая затычка GeForce 6600, система установлена, и всё бы прекрасно, но вот карта почему то греется в простое до 60 градусов. И ладно бы она что то показывала, НО, она была выключена через "echo 1 > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/remove", она не определяется в системе, на мониторе чёрный экран, да и сам монитор ушёл в энергосберегающий режим, но всё равно греется. Что можно сделать и что искать? Мне нужен сервер, а не домашняя печка.

Comment: От наличия драйвера видеокарты  в системе зависит скорость вращения вентилятора и тактовая частота видеокарты. Пока драйвер не загружен/не установлен - видеокарта молотит на полную катушку по дефолту.  Это Вам наводка...

Comment: Переключите видеокарту в текстовый режим програмно. это самый щядащий режим.

Comment: Как вариант - в разрыв питания PCI поставьте выключатель или реле. Цоколёвку найти не сложно. PCI и другие широкие интерфейсы - разрешает доставать устройства из разьема на гарячую (без перекоса, сам доставал). Часть контактов (по-питанию) для этой цели короче обычных (т.е. питание первым отключается на извлечение и последним включается при вставке). Включили карту, прошли биос, выключили.

Comment: @nick_n_a боюсь с реализацией Вашей идеи с реле у автора есть все шансы не только научиться паять и работать скальпилем, но и лишиться материнки (что скорее всего при отсутствии нужных навыков).

Comment: Паять я умею, в том числе и мелочь. А вот что пци поддерживает выдергивание на горячую не знал. Надо будет попробовать. Лежащая на столе видеокарта это лучше, чем программно отключенная.

Comment: @Cropinghigh пци по умолчанию не позволяет, пцие позволяет. Физически это две ну очень разные шины, не перепутайте! :)